# Search for value contained in a string format using dictionary method - Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, function

I have written a function for me to extract the the 'key' from 'values' (defined in my dictionary) that is contained in a column within my dataframe. This problem is best explained in codes below.

My problem is that my output column only returns the last 'key' that is searched upon. I would like all the keys to be returned.

Would appreciate any help!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'chat':['swimming is great for you! volleyball is fun too.',
                       'i like to cycle and run during my free time',
                      'apart from netball, i am good at basketball and diving too']})

sport_dic = {'team': ['basketball', 'soccer','volley','netball','hockey'],
 'individual': ['run','swim','cycl','div']}
```

My function:

```
def type_search(string,dic):
    for key,value in dic.items():
        return_x = []
        for v in value:
            if v in string:
                return_x.append(key)
                return(return_x)

df['chat_type'] = df['chat'].apply(lambda x: type_search(x,sport_dic))
```

What I got from my function:

```
df = {'chat': {0: 'swimming is great for you! volleyball is fun too.',
  1: 'i like to cycle and run during my free time',
  2: 'apart from netball, i am good at basketball and diving too'},

 'chat_type': {0: ['team'], 1: ['individual'], 2: ['team']}}
```

What I expect:

```
df = {'chat': {0: 'swimming is great for you! volleyball is fun too.',
  1: 'i like to cycle and run during my free time',
  2: 'apart from netball, i am good at basketball and diving too'},

 'chat_type': {0: ['individual','team'], 1: ['individual','individual'], 2: ['team','team','diving']}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'chat':['swimming is great for you! volleyball is fun too.',
                       'i like to cycle and run during my free time',
                      'apart from netball, i am good at basketball and diving too']})

sport_dic = {'team': ['basketball', 'soccer','volley','netball','hockey'],'individual': ['run','swim','cycl','div']}


def type_search(string,dic):
    return_x = []
    for key,value in dic.items():
        for v in value:
            if v in string:
                return_x.append(key)
    return(return_x)

df['chat_type'] = df['chat'].apply(lambda x: type_search(x,sport_dic))

df['chat_type']
```

output:

```
0          [team, individual]
1    [individual, individual]
2    [team, team, individual]
Name: chat_type, dtype: object
```

if you want to get your expected output use this line and get your desire output:

```
{i: df['chat_type'].tolist()[i] for i in range(len(df['chat_type'].tolist()))}
```

desire output:

```
{0: ['team', 'individual'],
 1: ['individual', 'individual'],
 2: ['team', 'team', 'individual']}
```